# Add extra hotkeys to the Annotate Tool?

Tags: customization, annotation

I'm trying to add a hotkey to the Annotate Tool so that I can hold down shift to draw a straight line.
I can find how to change the existing hotkey by searching for "annotate"

[image]

How can I add more hotkeys to the Annotate tool? (hold shift to draw straight lines mainly)

Comment: Not quite what you need, but SHIFT-SPACE > 7 will draw a straight line with the Annotation tool.

Comment: I think you are mistaking a different hotkey.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

The default shortcut for annotate straight-lines is `D + ALT + LMB`.

Change the hotkeys for that keymap.

[image]

Comment: I have the annotation tool hotkeyed, what I want to do is add a hotkey to draw a straight line when I have the annotation tool active. Like how Ctrl+LMB erases, I'd like to be able to hold down shift to draw a straight line.

Comment: I believe I've found the solution than. I edited my post.

Comment: Not exactly what I want, Ideally I'd like it to work like it does in photoshop where you can hold shift as a modifier to make straight lines but still be able to draw free-hand. I dont want to have to switch tool just to draw straight lines.
What Im looking for is how to add more hotkeys to the "Generic Tool: Annotate" like this: [Example Image](https://i.imgur.com/5zxaqia.jpg)
I guess I have to add a hotkey to change tool to draw straight lines, not ideal but maybe Blender cant do it any other way